# How can I build elements dynamically incrementing a number by one?

Tags: javascript

I am making a gallery. All images are named 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg etc - it extends all the way up to 200.jpg.

Copy and paste will be OK, but very time consuming.

```
  <div class="slideshow-container">
          <div class="slideshowDisplay fade">
            <img src="/images/media/1.jpg" width="100%">
          </div>

          <div class="slideshowDisplay fade">
            <img src="/images/media/2.jpg" width="100%">
          </div>

          <div class="slideshowDisplay fade">
            <img src="/images/media/3.jpg" width="100%">
          </div>
```

Can I use a for-loop or similar to create all the elements for me? My only problem is that, a for loop is used to repeat a code block multiple times is it not, so this for me wouldn't work.

Is there another way that I can create elements without having to spend a long time simply incrementing numbers by hand?

So far I have:

```
for(var i=0; i < 200; i++){
   var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
   newDiv.className = 'slideshowDisplay fade';
}
```

Nothing else...

Any guidance much appreciated.

Comment: Can you use JQuery?

Comment: Yes I can, that's not a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Basic DOM creation and appending***

You're only missing appending the new element to the `slideshow-container` and adding its content. You can use the `i` variable to create the increment image `src`.

```
var sc = document.querySelector(".slideshow-container")
for(var i=0; i < 200; i++){
   var newDiv = sc.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
   newDiv.className = 'slideshowDisplay fade';

   var img = newDiv.appendChild(document.createElement("img"));
   img.width="100%";
   img.src = "/images/media/" + (i + 1) + ".jpg";
}
```

---

***String concatenation***

The means of creating the `src` is called "string concatenation". In other words, we create a new string from multiple parts. First the `"/images/media/"` string, then the value of `i`, but adjusted up by one, and finally the `".jpg"` part.

---

***Making helper functions***

FWIW, it's nice to have a personal micro-library that you use to handle certain repetitive tasks. One such inclusion can be a function for creating new Elements.

```
function create(elem, props, par) {
  var el = document.createElement(elem)
  for (var p in props) {
    el[p] = props[p]
  }
  return par ? par.appendChild(el) : el
}
```

This takes a little verbosity out of creating and appending the new elements.

```
var sc = document.querySelector(".slideshow-container")
for(var i=0; i < 200; i++){
   var newDiv = create("div", {className: "slideshowDisplay fade"}, sc);
   create("img", {width: "100%", src: "/images/media/"+(i+1)+".jpg"}, newDiv);
}
```

---

***Different approach to a helper function***

Or instead of having the function receive the parent to which it is appended, you could allow it to receive an arbitrary number of child elements that it will append to itself.

```
function create(elem, props, ...children) {
  var el = document.createElement(elem)
  for (var p in props) {
    el[p] = props[p]
  }
  children.forEach(ch => el.appendChild(ch))
  return el
}
```

Then you can nest calls to `create` in a way that mirrors the new DOM structure.

```
var sc = document.querySelector(".slideshow-container")
for(var i=0; i < 200; i++){
   sc.appendChild(
     create("div", {className: "slideshowDisplay fade"}, 
       create("img", {width: "100%", src: "/images/media/"+(i+1)+".jpg"})
     )
   );
}
```

Comment: I would add the piece of code to append to created div to its parent: here the 'slideshow-container'

Comment: @ValLeNain: Yep, that's been added. Forgot it at first.

Comment: @squint as a beginner, a lot of this has gone over my head. That is as expected. If I was after 'further reading' for this kind of topic, what should I Google? I find some elements of JS I use more than others. Does this fall under anything specific I can research further?

Comment: @davvv: Depends on which parts you're confused about. If you're not sure what a particular method does, then best to just search for that term. Otherwise, I would tinker with the code to see how various changes affect it. Embed `console.log()` to print values to the console so that you can see what's happening as the code runs.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need just one parent div in your DOM. Then just use functions like `document.createElement` and `appendChild` to store the newly created divs with pictures inside the parent element.

```js
var source = "/images/media/";
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.className = 'slideshowDisplay fade';
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = source + i + '.jpg';
  img.width = '100%';
  newDiv.appendChild(img);
  parent.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container" id='parent'>

</div>
```